# Does this completely free both structs

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I have these two structs

```c
typedef struct WordNode
{
    char value[69];
    struct WordNode *next;
} WordNode;

typedef struct Node
{
    char target[69];
    WordNode *childern; // Depends on
    WordNode *parents;  // Is depened open
    WordNode *commands;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

Then I free them with these function at the end

```c
/*
 void freeWordNode(WordNode *head)- frees a WordNode
 linkedlist.
*/
void freeWordNode(WordNode *head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        WordNode *nextNode = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = nextNode;
    }
}
/*
  void freeNode(Node *head)- free the nodes and all 
  its hanging mallocs
*/
void freeNode(Node *head)
{

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        Node *nextNode = head->next;
        // Free hanging mallocs
        WordNode *children = head->childern;
        WordNode *parents = head->parents;
        WordNode *commands = head->commands;
        freeWordNode(children);
        freeWordNode(parents);
        freeWordNode(commands);
        // Free head
        free(head);
        // set head to next node
        head = nextNode;
    }
}
```

I get this message in valgrind:

```
==2997875== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2997875==     in use at exit: 984 bytes in 12 blocks
==2997875==   total heap usage: 23 allocs, 11 frees, 11,400 bytes allocated
==2997875== 
==2997875== 240 (160 direct, 80 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 6
==2997875==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2997875==    by 0x109756: makeTargetStrAndDepStrs (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875==    by 0x1099B9: loopThroughFile (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875==    by 0x109B84: readFile (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875==    by 0x109E8F: main (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875== 
==2997875== 320 (80 direct, 240 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 6
==2997875==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2997875==    by 0x10A247: addToVisted (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875==    by 0x109C16: postOrderHelper (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875==    by 0x109C9B: postOrderHelper (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875==    by 0x109E1E: postOrder (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875==    by 0x109EAD: main (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875== 
==2997875== 424 (104 direct, 320 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==2997875==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2997875==    by 0x10A02B: makeNode (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875==    by 0x109A2C: loopThroughFile (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875==    by 0x109B84: readFile (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875==    by 0x109E8F: main (in /home/fieldsierra/csc352/assg9/prob1/Main)
==2997875== 
==2997875== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2997875==    definitely lost: 344 bytes in 4 blocks
==2997875==    indirectly lost: 640 bytes in 8 blocks
==2997875==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2997875==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2997875==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2997875==
```

Am I freeing everything with these structs?? Or does is another part of my code that doesn't have to with these structs causing the memory leak. Also all the functions mentioned have to do with these structs
`makeNode()` makes a Node. `addToVisted()` adds a WordNode to a WordNode linked list. `makeTargetStrAndDepStrs()` frees the nodes in case `calloc` returns NULL;

Comment: Please run `valgrind --leak-check=full` and paste the full output.

Comment: I updated it thank you

Comment: You clearly do have memory leaks.  But you haven't shown enough code for us to understand why.

Comment: I'm just going to rewrite my whole code cause I can't share all of it here. And check `valgrind --leak-check=full` every time I mess around with `calloc`. Thanks for the help though